# Compare std::vector of pairs with pugi::xml_object_range attributes

Tags: c++, c++11, pugixml

I'm writing some convenience functions for my XML parser based on [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/), and now I have the problem that I want to retrieve only XML nodes with a specific attribute name and value!

XML example:

```
<Readers>
    <Reader measurement="..." type="Mighty">
        <IP reader="1">192.168.1.10</IP>
        <IP reader="2">192.168.1.25</IP>
        <IP reader="3">192.168.1.30</IP>
        <IP reader="4">192.168.1.50</IP>    
    </Reader>
    <Reader measurement="..." type="Standard">
        ...
    </Reader>
</Readers>
```

My try:

```
std::string GetNodeValue(std::string node, std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> &attributes)
{
    pugi::xml_node xmlNode = m_xmlDoc.select_single_node(("//" + node).c_str()).node();

    // get all attributes
    pugi::xml_object_range<pugi::xml_attribute_iterator> nodeAttributes(xmlNode.attributes());

    // logic to compare given attribute name:value pairs with parsed ones
    // ...
}
```

Can someone help me or give me a hint?! (maybe with Lambda Expressions)

Comment: Is that valid XML? :o

Answer (score -1):

To solve this we have to use [XPath](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#xpath).

```
/*!
    Create XPath from node name and attributes

    @param XML node name
    @param vector of attribute name:value pairs
    @return XPath string
*/
std::string XmlParser::CreateXPath(std::string node, std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> &attributes)
{
    try
    {       
        // create XPath
        std::string xpath = node + "[";
        for(auto it=attributes.begin(); it!=attributes.end(); it++)
            xpath += "@" + it->first + "='" + it->second + "' and ";
        xpath.replace(xpath.length()-5, 5, "]");        

        return xpath;
    }
    catch(std::exception exp)
    {       
        return "";
    }
}
```

`CreateXPath` constructs a valid XML XPath statement from given node name and attribute list.

```
/*!
    Return requested XmlNode value

    @param name of the XmlNode
    @param filter by given attribute(s) -> name:value   
    @return value of XmlNode or empty string in case of error
*/
std::string XmlParser::GetNodeValue(std::string node, std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> &attributes /* = std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>() */)
{   
    try
    {
        std::string nodeValue = "";     

        if(attributes.size() != 0) nodeValue = m_xmlDoc.select_node(CreateXPath(node, attributes).c_str()).node().child_value();            
        else nodeValue = m_xmlDoc.select_node(("//" + node).c_str()).node().child_value();          

        return nodeValue;
    }
    catch(std::exception exp) 
    {           
        return ""; 
    }
}
```